# Identity Db : Duplicate email error even if constraint not set on the column

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am getting an exception of duplicate email in the identitydb while creating a user from my asp.net api.
The strange thing is that there is no constraint set on the email column or normalised email column so not
sure why it is not allowing me to enter same email address. Is there some default setting in the identity db for checking email dulication

Error

```
Code : "DuplicateEmail"
Description : "Email 'test@test.com' is already taken."
```

Execption caught while tracing in the profiler

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC GlobalExceptionInsert @DateTimeStamp, @Thread, @Class, @Method, @UserName, @Message, @Exception',N'@DateTimeStamp nvarchar(23),@Thread nvarchar(2),@Class nvarchar(13),@Method nvarchar(8),@UserName nvarchar(17),@Message nvarchar(115),@Exception nvarchar(163)',@DateTimeStamp=N'2019/10/23 14:26:13.078',@Thread=N'15',@Class=N'<AddUser>d__7',@Method=N'MoveNext',@UserName=N'Argentex.Core.Api',@Message=N'Error creating new user tmenon. Message: Code: DuplicateEmail. Description: Email ''test@test.com'' is already taken.',@Exception=N'Argentex.Core.Api.Exceptions.IdentityException: Error creating new user tmenon. Message: Code: DuplicateEmail. Description: Email ''test@test.com'' is already taken.'
```

Here is the screenshot of the table

Table

[image]

Constraint

[image]

Table definition

```
USE [IdentityDB_CSR]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[User]    Script Date: 23/10/2019 13:28:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AuthUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [Forename] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ClientCompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClientCompanyContactId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedByAuthUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PhoneNumberMobile] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberOther] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ASPNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ASPCreationDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [LastTelephoneChange] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [LastEmailChange] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [LastPasswordChange] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [IsApproved] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Birthday] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Position] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PrimaryContact] [bit] NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsAdmin] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ApprovedByAuthUserId] [int] NULL,
    [IsAuthorisedSignatory] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsSignatory] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [AK_User_AuthUserId] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [AuthUserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [LastPasswordChange]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreateDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsAuthorisedSignatory]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsSignatory]
GO
```

Definition for UserNameIndex

```
USE [IdentityDB_CSR]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

/****** Object:  Index [UserNameIndex]    Script Date: 23/10/2019 13:58:00 ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex] ON [dbo].[User]
(
    [NormalizedUserName] ASC
)
WHERE ([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: `Post the error`

Comment: We really need the error, `INSERT` statement, and full DDL of your table (include Keys, constraints, and unique indexes). Those images tell but a small part of the story, and we can't see the definitions of your objects through an image.

Comment: @Larnu , I have updated the post

Comment: That error you've posted isn't a SQL Server error; where is it coming from? Also, you haven't Included the `INSERT` statement and definition for `UserNameIndex`.

Comment: @Tom this is still not clear. From the code you posted, there is no proof that your problem is anywhere in the database schema. Post the SQL error message that you're getting.

Comment: The problem is likely on the C# side of the fence, e.g.: the `MembershipProvider.CreateUser(...)` method is probably calling `connect.CheckEmail(email)` and failing with `MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail`.

Comment: I searched the keyword DuplicateEmail and CheckEmail in my c# code but none was found

Comment: When i google I can see that this is probably default behaviour within Asp.net core identity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityerrordescriber.duplicateemail?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 1):

When creating user with ASP.NET Core Identity , it will raise the default `UserValidator` library which will make sure email is not empty, valid, and unique if `options.User.RequireUniqueEmail` of `IdentityOptions` is true :

```
if (manager.Options.User.RequireUniqueEmail)
{
    await ValidateEmail(manager, user, errors);
}
```

`ValidateEmail` :

```
// make sure email is not empty, valid, and unique
private async Task ValidateEmail(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user, List<IdentityError> errors)
{
    var email = await manager.GetEmailAsync(user);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
    {
        errors.Add(Describer.InvalidEmail(email));
        return;
    }
    if (!new EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(email))
    {
        errors.Add(Describer.InvalidEmail(email));
        return;
    }
    var owner = await manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
    if (owner != null && 
        !string.Equals(await manager.GetUserIdAsync(owner), await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user)))
    {
        errors.Add(Describer.DuplicateEmail(email));
    }
}
```

[Source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserValidator.cs)

You can set the options in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
    ...
});
```